# How to execute Kotlin code in an IntelliJ plugin?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, kotlin, intellij-plugin

I want to build an IntelliJ Idea plugin, which

- detects that a certain Kotlin class appears in a source code file (e. g. `SomeGraph`) and
- if there such class, executes the code and displays the result in a side pane.

The Kotlin code as a low-end DSL.

[image: Mockup]

For example, let's say I have the following piece of code:

```
val vertex1 = GraphElement()
val vertex2 = GraphElement()

fun main(args : Array<String>) {
  val myGraph = SomeGraph()
  // Initialize graph, add data to it
  myGraph.addEdge(vertex1, vertex2)

  // Now myGraph.toDot() will return a Graphviz dot diagram in text form
}
```

`myGraph.toDot()` will return the code of a [Graphviz Dot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_(graph_description_language)) graph (`digraph G {...`).

My plugin needs to take this text, let Dot render the graph and display the graph.

Is it technically possible? If yes, how can I execute a piece of Kotlin code from inside an IntelliJ plugin?

Notes:

1. The DSL file doesn't need to have a `main` function. If it would make things easier, I could change the place where `SomeGraph` is created.

E. g. this would be a perfectly fine alternative to the DSL code above:

```
class SpecialCaseGraph : SomeGraph() {
  fun init() {
    val vertex1 = GraphElement()
    val vertex2 = GraphElement()
    myGraph.addEdge(vertex1, vertex2)
  }
  fun toDot():String {
    // Returns the Dot representation of the graph
  }
}
```

2. The [PlantUML](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7017-plantuml-integration) plugin does something similar. The only difference to what I want to do is that the diagram must be generated based on the code being displayed (as opposed to PlantUML, which converts diagram descripiton language into Dot code).

[image: Image showing the difference to PlantUML]

**Update 1 (02.09.2017 19:53 MSK):**

Tried to get the `ScriptEngine` for Kotlin using the following code snipped from [Kotlin forum](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/embedding-kotlin-as-scripting-language-in-java-apps/2211/6).

```
ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();

  List<ScriptEngineFactory> factories = mgr.getEngineFactories();

  for (ScriptEngineFactory factory : factories) {

      System.out.println("ScriptEngineFactory Info");

      String engName = factory.getEngineName();
      String engVersion = factory.getEngineVersion();
      String langName = factory.getLanguageName();
      String langVersion = factory.getLanguageVersion();

      System.out.printf("\tScript Engine: %s (%s)%n", engName, engVersion);

      List<String> engNames = factory.getNames();
      for(String name : engNames) {
          System.out.printf("\tEngine Alias: %s%n", name);
      }

      System.out.printf("\tLanguage: %s (%s)%n", langName, langVersion);

  }
```

Unfortunately, there is no Kotlin engine, when I execute this code.

[image: Screenshot showing the scripting engines available in my plugin]

Comment: Kotlin has a [intermediate code representation](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/tree/master/compiler/frontend/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/psi) but it doesn't seem like you can execute it

Comment: [Kotlin docs](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew11.html#javaxscript-support) have a more detailed example pointing to [github](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/tree/master/libraries/examples/kotlin-jsr223-local-example). Inside the [pom file](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/examples/kotlin-jsr223-local-example/pom.xml#L30-L39) we can see that it depends on `kotlin-compiler` and `kotlin-script-util`. Make sure you have those in your pom as well and then retry using the scripting engine

Comment: Also, see [this](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/embedding-kotlin-as-scripting-language-in-java-apps/2211/9?u=mibac138) post if you haven't already